# How do I install a newer version of GTK in Ubuntu without replacing the current one?

Tags: linux, compile, glib

I am trying to compile file-roller from git, but running autogen.sh gives me this error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 2.91.1) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I am running Ubuntu Maverick and don't wish to completely replace my current version of gtk, glib, etc.

I have tried to compile GTK using the --prefix argument of autogen.sh, but this gives me a similar error about my version of glib.

How can I successfully compile file-roller using these new libraries without borking my install?

Comment: I have used the --prefix argument of autogen.sh to install glib under ~/glib, but I don't know how to compile gtk using this directory, and I assume that glib is not the only library that gtk will need a newer version of

Comment: At least nowadays, the `HACKING` doc in the root of the repo very clearly states that to build the `git` version of `gtk+`, you must first build the `git` versions of `glib`, `pango`, and `atk`.

Answer (score 0):

You have generally two options:

- Tell each new software package that needs `gtk`, *at configure time*, where to look for the right libraries, or
- Install new GTK side-by-side in a system location that is in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The first option is simple and safe if you want to build (including compilation) just a few programs that depend on the new Gtk. There are different ways of pointing a software at a specific library location, depending on the configuration tool it uses. For classic applications with `configure` script, you'd need to have a look at configure phase options using `./configure --help`. Look for things like `--gtk-lib=PATH` or `--with-gtk-path=PATH`. The `--with` part (common to many options) will usually be mentioned only once at the beginning of the help.

However, the File-roller you mention seems to be using `autogen` program for automated configuration procedure. The snippet you pasted indicates, what *environment variables* you need to set in order to point at a specific GTK+ path. It looks like running `GTK_LIBS=/full/path/to/your/custom/lib ./autogen.sh` should be enough.

A system-wide scenario is a bit more tricky, because each Linux distribution can manage the library paths in a bit different way, so I can't give you a universal solution.