# How to install a new version of Gtk without overwriting the current version?

Tags: linux, installation, gtk

There is a similar question without answer : [How do I install a newer version of GTK in Ubuntu without replacing the current one?](https://superuser.com/questions/214203)

I'm running a Fedora 10 - Gnome - Gtk 2.0.

Wireshark needs Gtk+ > 2.4 to be compilated so I choose to install Gtk+2.24.

I do not really understand the influence of the option `--disable-modules`?

Can you confirm that this will only install the new libraries and my platform will not use them?

Comment: Why don't you want to just update `Gtk+` to version `2.24`?

Comment: @jankes I want the minimum impact on my devel platform. This platform stands as an installation target.

Comment: I see. If it's just for one app, then you can try to only *build* the 2.24 version, without installing (i.e. `make` without `make install`) or configure it to be installed in a different `$PREFIX` (path). You'd then have to point wireshark to the path the custom `Gtk+`. See `./configure --help` for each sources.